# WSL Kernel Netfilter hooks for Pre/Post Routing not available

Tags: linux-kernel, windows-subsystem-for-linux, netfilter, nftables

I'm on Windows 11, WSL2, kernel 5.10.60.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2.

I'm using a RHEL distribution and I'm trying to enable a netfilter NAT rule.  The problem is I receive this error if I try to add a rule to the NAT table for Pre or PostRouting:

```
[root@rhel8 nftables]# nft add chain nat prerouting { type nat hook prerouting priority 0 \; }
Error: No such file or directory
add chain nat prerouting { type nat hook prerouting priority 0 ; }
          ^^^
```

My googling leads me to believe that I need to add some kernel configuration in order to make this work, but from what I can tell from the Microsoft defaults, everything appears to be switched on.  If there is a kernel guru out there who can give me a hint I'd appreciate it!

Comment: I'm *guessing* there's a programming/development reason behind your question, but it's not really stated there, so it comes off as more Linux/kernel/networking related.  Could I recommend that you make sure it's clear to the rest of us that it's on-topic with an edit?  Thanks!

Comment: Kernel config is something one must set before recompiling the Kernel.  I need some help from a kernel developer familiar with Netfilter.

Answer (score 0):

For prosperity for anyone who hits this error:

I pulled the microsoft WSL kernel (https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel.git) then copied the ./Microsoft/config-wsl to .config to seed the kernel compilation.

Ran `make config` to step through the answers until the netfilter section of the compilation, then answered yes to the entire section on netfilter, including NAT etc.

```
make -j $(nproc)
```

Once the kernel compiled, I copied the x86 (not x86_64) ./arch/x86/boot/bzImage to something reachable on the windows file system (`/mnt/c/users/me/xxxx`).

Then make a backup of, then edit your `c:\users\me\.wslconfig` and update kernel to be the new  kernel (remembering that you must use `\\` in the path to the kernel e.g. `c:\\users\\me\\bzimage_custom`.  Finally restart WSL to boot the new kernel:

```
wsl --shutdown
wsl -d mydistro
```

Then you will have NAT available :).